# ubuntu mate will not log on after changing one of my init login scripts

Tags: gnome, pulseaudio, ubuntu-19.10

I was having some issues with switching my audio output (ie I plug in HDMI, if an application is currently running its audio through the computer's speakers, the audio does not move to the HDMI unless I kill the pulseaudio session and restart the program) and tried adding some scripts that run at login but can't remember what they are (not smart).  I know I put, for example, `pulseaudio -k` somewhere.

Anyway, I get to a login screen as usual but after I enter my credentials it flashes the dell screen then goes right back to login. I can login using the terminal. I am certain that I broke my system when adding these custom scripts as something related to them comes up after I login using the terminal.

I just want to basically reset my desktop without losing my files, and perhaps internet bookmarks, as I have given up on trying to see where the offending code is, but if there is an easy way to find this then I'm all ears. Maybe there is a way, for example, to restore my desktop to its factory settings from the terminal without touching my documents?

```
Ubuntu 19.10 PHILLIP-Precision-5520 tty

PHILLIP-Precision-5520 login: PHILLIP Password:

Last login: Sun Apr 19 13:46:31 EDT 2020 on tty4 Welcome to Ubuntu 19.10 (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64)

* Management:

* Support:

* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com https://landscape.canonical.com https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be installed immediately.

0 of these updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Failed to kill PulseAudio daemon.

Toggling output devices (Speakers/Headset) No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

Moving input: to sink:

Setting default sink to:

Can't open display E: (pulseaudio) main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process PHILLIP (master #) $ ==
```

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: i'm a newb, thanks for letting me know and being polite about it.